# iOS 8 Swift NSFetchResult predicate with Core Data relationship can't access internal ID

Tags: ios, swift, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Very new to Core Data but I've read that I can fetch data that uses Entity relationships. Now, coming from Mysql maybe I'm making too many assumptions, but I have 2 Entities set up with a Relationship between them and I can't fetch the proper data.

Here are my 2 models:

```
@objc(Categories)
class Categories: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var category: String
    @NSManaged var exp: String
    @NSManaged var order: NSNumber
}

@objc(Techniques)
class Techniques: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var korean: String
    @NSManaged var order: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var spanish: String
    @NSManaged var categories: Categories
}
```

After I created a Relationship from Techniques to Categories, Core Data added this field to the Sqlite DB:

```
ZCATEGORIES - INTEGER
```

Let's say I want to fetch all Techniques that belong to the category #3 (with internal ZID: 3)

If I do this:

```
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "categories == %@", 3)
```

It works. But if I do:

```
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "categories == %@", category.category)
```

It doesn't work. I understand that it doesn't work because `category.category` is a String, not an Integer.

My question is:

Do I have to create my own relationhip IDs field in the Category Entity and set that, then reference the Technique like:

```
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "categories == %@", category.categoryID)
```

?

Isn't there a way to access the Category's internal ID to get this relationship to work?

Or better yet, it would seem to me that there should be an internal mechanish to retrieve these relationships without writing a SQL-like query but just using the Object, something like: `Techniques.categores`.

Thanks. I haven't found a good answer anywhere.

Comment: That's a really unhelpful attitude you have there, the least you could do is point me to a link where this is easy to find. I've been searching for 2 days now and can't seem to find it that's why I posted this here. Maybe I'm an idiot, but your response does absolutely nothing to further the SO cause of helping others.

Comment: First Google result for "Core Data relationship" https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdRelationships.html Fourth result for "NSFetchRequest relationship" http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started. That second link will talk you through everything that you are currently trying to do. I'm not saying you're an idiot, I'm saying that StackOverflow is not an excuse to not go out and research answers.

Comment: I think maybe you don't understand the question because in neither of these links does it talk about fetching relationship data. Furthermore, they're both in objective-c while the title of the question clearly says Swift.  If they were useful links I could try to parse the info but they're not. I guess you were right in your original intention, better to downvote and stay silent, at least it's less of a waste of my time.

Comment: Objective-C, Swift, it really doesn't matter. You are accessing the same set of APIs. The syntax might be slightly different but the methods are exactly the same. Second link, one quarter of the way down it is setting up a relationship between FailedBankInfo and FailedBankDetails. First, you don't have an inverse relationship. If you did have (which it explains in the link) it means you can just access `category.technique` or whatever. Second, how is it I was able to find this info out without having to resort to SO?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing an attribute name, so the predicate knows which attribute of the category class to compare. This way you won't need to use the internal unique ID. Although it can be derived (and would work) it's not the way to go with Core Data, who is trying to abstract that information for you.

```
let categoryPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "categories.category == %@", category.category)
```

As mentioned setting up an inverse relationship is recommended. It allows Core Data to maintain the consistency of the object graph, and can be used to go from a category to it's techniques.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That worked, that's quite helpful and clears up the database misconception I had. I think some people on this website could learn a lot from you.

Answer (score 1):

As you solved friend?

[image]

[image]

```
import UIKit
import CoreData


let appdelegado:AppDelegate =  UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
let contexto2:NSManagedObjectContext =  appdelegado.managedObjectContext


class Consultar: UIViewController {

    let marca =  Marca()
    let modelo =  Modelo()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //Consultando con diferente contextp

        let entityMarca = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Modelo", inManagedObjectContext: contexto2)

        let oderBy = NSSortDescriptor(key: "nombre", ascending: true)
        let consulta = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Modelo")
        consulta.sortDescriptors = [oderBy]
        //???¿¿???¿¿???¿ HELP
        let predicate  =  NSPredicate(format: "modelo.marca = %@",)
        consulta.entity = entityMarca
        consulta.predicate = predicate
        //let arrayResultado:[NSArray] = try!contexto.executeFetchRequest(consulta) as! [NSArray]
        //if let resultado = try?contexto.executeFetchRequest(consulta) where resultado.count  > 0{
        if let arrayResultado:[NSArray] = try!contexto.executeFetchRequest(consulta) as! [NSArray] where arrayResultado.count > 0{
            for x in arrayResultado {
                print("\n ====================DATOS RECUPERADOS======================")
                print(x)
//              print(x.valueForKey("nombre")!)
//              print(x.valueForKey("marca")!)
            }

        }else{
            print("Sin modelos")
        }

    }
}
```